# Ensuring docker containers have certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I have an issue where a self-signed certificate has been added to a testing environment.

So this means my selenium grid that is hosted in Docker containers is unable to get to this environment due to the certificate.

I get this error when executing tests

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://xxx.xx.x.x:4444/wd/hub/session/0ee03d72bff0d5527cff926121b496bb/url timed out after 60 seconds.
>     ----> System.Net.WebException : The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
>   TearDown : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://xxx.xx.x.x:4444/wd/hub/session/0ee03d72bff0d5527cff926121b496bb/screenshot timed out after 60 seconds.
>     ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out

The docker environment is set up with docker-compose and using chrome and hub images.

Compose file is this

```
version: "3"
services:
selenium-hub:
image: selenium/hub:latest
container_name: selenium-hub
ports:
  - "4444:4444"
chrome:
image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
volumes:
  - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
depends_on:
  - selenium-hub
environment:
  - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
  - HUB_PORT=4444
```

I added the certificates to the host hoping this would be enough but obviously not as each container is separated.

My question is how do I insert the certificates into each chrome node that spins up?

**More information**

When running a curl from within the container I get the following error

> @b94ed81b0110:/etc# curl https://xxxx.xxxx.co.uk
>   curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
>   establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
>   how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

But I have installed the required certificates to the container

```
root@b94ed81b0110:/etc# update-ca-certificates 
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
2 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Adding debian:admin.pem
Adding debian:assessor.pem
done.
done.
```

Comment: are you just trying to test dockerized selenium-grid? and what is the use case for using self-sign certificate on each containers
?

Comment: No, I am trying to run tests on the selenium grid and the target environment of these tests has a self-signed certificate. So the chrome instance in the container needs to know about that certificate otherwise it won't be able to load the application.

Comment: I faced similar kind of issue while adding proxy certificate to node containers. I collected the steps to add certificate via command line and added those steps to dockerfile  of node and rebuild those images.

Comment: @Akshaybarahate I don't suppose you could share those steps? Or point me in the correct direction

Comment: Before I suggest anything.Without docker in the simple selenium-grid setup . Where do you configure those certs?. At Os level in keytools or in Browser.  In my case it was a browser. So Based on answer I will suggest the steps.

Comment: On my mac, I have done this at the OS level, same with my windows VM. But the selenium-grid is sat on a small VM in Azure so it's a different ball game.

Comment: @Akshaybarahate I have managed to install the certs into one of the nodes but the test is still failing with that error which seems to suggest its more of a networking issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193514/discussion-between-akshay-barahate-and-brian-mitchell).

Comment: @Akshaybarahate  I am facing similar issue, wherein I need to add .p12 certificate on my chrome browser to run my application. But I am not sure how it can be added to my chrome docker image. Any help is appreciated.